# Block Chain Size?

Tags: blockchain

I was wondering what the block chain size is on everyone's system.  I have fully synchronized and find that the chain data folder continues to slowly increase in size, as is to be expected.

However, I know the size of the file can differ quite a bit.  I am wondering what size your files are on different machines and when synchronizing via different methods.

My current chaindata folder shows a size of 28.4 gb.

I performed the sync with:

- OS: windows 10 64-bit system
- CPU: i5 3507K (no OC)
- GPU: gtx 670 (don't think this matters at all during synchronization)
- RAM: 16 gb DDR3 2400mhz (running at 1600mhz)
- HD: SSD Samsung 840 256gb

Initial sync was performed by:

```
geth --fast --cache=4024
```

I believe I was fully fast synced within 4 hours of initiating with a Samsung 840 SSD and 16 gb of RAM, but from what I understand, geth will only use the ram that you assigned via the 'cache' modifier, so I am assuming it was using 4 gb of system RAM to speed things up.

Processor is a i5 3507K.  System is liquid cooled, but during the synch process, I did see CPU temps move into the mid 50's to 60C range.

Also, after full sync.  I closed the geth synch command prompt window shell and then used:

`geth --cache=4024` to catch up again after stopping the synch for a little while to see if I would have any issues re-initiating synchonization.

Just wondering what chaindata file sizes are on other people's systems

Comment: @TravisJacobs, it is definitely in the same line of questioning.  I was just trying to get a range of numbers currently for various users out there in terms of block chain size on different systems and with different configurations.  It might give people a better ideal as to how long they need to wait until they have synchronized the full block chain when starting for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

160.55 GB is the full chain up to block 3,985,180 on a Mac.

Comment: Wow, that's getting up there!

Comment: It's becoming unmanageable.